# Codeigniter Ion auth user session conflict

Tags: codeigniter-3, ion-auth

My website is built with codeigniter framework and I am using Ion auth library for user management. A very strange problem I am facing, the login shown to me was of a different user, may be both of us accessed site at the same time but location is completely different. Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: same happen with me  , and some time its looging out users properly.

Comment: Same here in 2018.